# passing variables in 'bind' trigger

Tags: binding, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js with jquery droppable.

The problem I'm having is that upon entering the `.droppable` function, the 'this' no longer refers to the backbone object. I've read Yehuda Katz article about understanding 'this', but I  still don't understand how to 'solve' the problem. 
http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

I thought the way out of the issue would be to just bind the model changes event to trigger a method, but I need to pass a variable to the method, and I can't figure out how to do that.

here's an excerpt of my code. On the line `MyApp.User.Trigger('new_class');`, is there a way to add a variable?? How do I put that in the bind event??

```
initialize: function(){
    user = MyApp.User;
    MyApp.User.bind('new_class',this.save, this);
    this.render();
},

render: function(){

    $('li.empty').droppable({

        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        start: function(e){
            $(this).click('unbind');
        },
        drop: function(event, ui){
            var add_class_to_user = $(this).attr('data-id');
             MyApp.User.Trigger('new_class');
        }
    })

},

save: function(class){
    var add_class = new Myapp.Model.Class({ 
        class_id: class,
        user_id: user.id
    });
    add_class.save()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand what you are asking,
so i will answer both :

***on the context of This:***

and why don't you store reference this into a new variable?

```
...

render: function(){
    // here we put this in a new variable myView.
    var myView = this;

    $('li.empty').droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        start: function(e){
            $(this).click('unbind');

            // here you can use myView instead of this, if you want something from your view.
            myView.model.set({'name', 'newname'});

        },
        drop: function(event, ui){
            var add_class_to_user = $(this).attr('data-id');
             MyApp.User.Trigger('new_class');
        }
    })
},

...
```

***on the question of passing parameters to an event***

```
...

render: function(){
    $('li.empty').droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        start: function(e){
            $(this).click('unbind');
        },
        drop: function(event, ui){
            var add_class_to_user = $(this).attr('data-id');
             MyApp.User.Trigger('new_class', add_class_to_user);
        }
    })
},

...
```

in your user model you should of course do this: (or more likely in another view, you can bind to that event on the user model)

```
MyApp.User.bind('new_class', function(myparameter) {
    alert('yay, my parameter is:'  + myparameter);
    $('#myElement').addClass(myparameter);
});
```

example in jsfiddle: can be found here....
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/MWuHj/

Comment: thanks Sander, I went with the adding the events to the user model, as I agree that is probably the right way to do it.

Comment: well, that is exactly what i mean, you can trigger the event on the user, but you can bind to it from anywhere, usually you don't bind in the user itself if you want a class in the DOM to be changed, since DOM is the view's responsability, so a UserView could bind to his user model and add the class for you...